# New Computer and No Wi-Fi or Bluetoooth connection

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth

Just got a new computer, installed Ubuntu **16.04**, and figured out I have no Wi-Fi. I have attempted to install ndiswrapper and try to use the windows drivers, but I might not have installed ndiswrapper correctly because it it missing something. Thanks!

EDIT: I have a HP Spectre x360 (late 2016) and I believe that it has an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 network card (PCI)

Comment: No mention of computer model? network card model? ubuntu release?

Comment: Sorry, that would be helpful I guess. I added them.

Comment: Using a distro released in the first quarter of 2016 with a late 2016 hardware might not be a good idea, maybe you try Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: I never thought of that, can I simply install 16.10 over 16.04 or would you recommend a installation over 16.04 (overwrite)?

Comment: EDIT: I meant upgrade to 16.10

Comment: A new installation is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the 4.8 kernel and firmware from Ubuntu 16.10 in 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```

Reboot